# Manipulate part of image

Tags: manipulate, image

I have 2 images that I combined `image1` on top and `image2` bottom:

```
combine = ImageAssemble[{{image1}, {image2}}]
```

[image]

Now I want to manipulate the bottom image while showing both images. I tried:

```
Manipulate[Show[image1, ImageTransformation[image2,Sin[a Pi #]^2&,{a, -1,4}]]]
```

but [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) gave an error as it expects graphics.

I then thought `ImageTake` might help and tried:

```
Manipulate[ImageTransformation[ImageTake[combine,-150],Sin[a Pi #]^2&,{a, -1,4}]]
```

I was left out with only the bottom picture (cropped the image).

I would appreciate any suggestions to show both images but manipulate only the second one.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. I suggest you [edit] your question to clarify, otherwise the question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, next time try to use the correct [formatting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). (Follow the links).

Comment: @rhermans Thanks for the links. I've added an example image and an example transformation function. I am trying to apply this function to only the bottom half of the assembled image. Let me know if the question needs more clarification, and how.

Answer (score 1):

I might try to do the transformation inside the ImageAssemble:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}];
ImageAssemble[{{img}, {ImageTransformation[img, Sin[Pi #]^2 &]}}]
```

[image]

To use this in a Manipulate is then straightforward:

```
Manipulate[ImageAssemble[{{img}, {ImageTransformation[img, 
      Sin[Pi a # ]^2 &]}}], {a, 0.2, 2}]
```